# Find all the groups of order 28

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, groups-enumeration

I've seen there is a similar question, but it looks for something more specific. I'll write what I thought.

I've rapidly seen that every group of order 28 has a unique normal subgroup of order 7. Then exists an element $a$ such that $\langle a \rangle =: H$ is normal.

I have that it has to be 1 2-Sylow or 7 2-Sylow subgroups. If there is only 1, then $G$ is abelian, so $G \cong \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_7$ or $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_7$.

If there are 7 2-Sylow subgroups, I have a harder time finding the possibilities. If there exists an $b \in G$ such that $|\langle b \rangle|=2$ and $\langle a,b \rangle = G$, then, since $H$ is normal, $b ab^{-1}=a^m$ for $m\in\mathbb{N}$, the $ba=a^mb$. Then:

$$a=b^2a=ba^mb=a^{m^2}b^2=a^{m^2}$$

Then $a^{m^2-1}=1$ so, for Lagrange, $7|m^2-1=(m+1)(m-1)$. I can assume $0 <m <7$ so this leaves me with $m=1$ or $m=6$.

If $m=1$, then $ab=ba$ meaning $G$ is abelian, but it's also generated from elements of order 7 and 2, but there are no elements of order 4 and only one element of order 2, so it's not possible.

If $m=6$, since $\langle a,b \rangle=G$, the mapping $a \rightarrow r$ and $b \rightarrow s$ shows me that $G \cong D_{14}$ the dihedral group.

So, I'm left with the case that $\langle a, b \rangle \neq G$. If I'm not mistaken, I have two cases: either exists another element $c \neq b$ with order 2, or I have a $c$ with order 4 such that $\langle a,c \rangle = G$. I think both cases are the same, but don't know how to justify it.

**EDIT**

In the first case, I've found that $G\cong D_7 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$. I'm not sure why this is the only non-abelian group formed by 3 elements, with order 7, 2 and 2 respectively.

If $c$ has order 4, then, with the same analysis as before, $ca = ac$ or $ca = a^6c$. In the first case, $G$ is abelian so is a case seen before. In the second case, I'm not sure how to continue. I'm not completely sure if it has to be $\mathbb{Z}_7 $⋊$ \mathbb{Z}_4$ for some indirect product, but I'm not sure how to find all functions such that is an indirect product

Comment: In the case you argue that $G$ is abelian, you might want a longer argument. If there is a single $2$-Sylow subgroup $N$, we know $N$ must be normal in $G,$ but why does that make $G$ abelian? (It's not hard to prove, just needs one or two more statements.)

Comment: You also haven't seemed to have dealt with the case where there are elements of order $4.$ If $b$ is of order $4,$ we can again get $bab=a^m$ where $m=1,6.$ If $m=6$ you have a different group $\mathbb Z_7\rtimes\mathbb Z_4.$ (The condition on $m$ here is $m^4-1=(m^2-1)(m^2+1)$ is divisible by $7,$ but no $m^2+1$ is divisible by $7,$ so $m=1,6.$)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews If there is a single 2-Sylow, then $|N|=4$, so $N$ is abelian. $H$ is abelian since it's cyclic. Since $NH < G$ and $|NH| \geq 28 = |G|$, $NH = G$ and since $N \ cap H = {1}$ for orden issues and $nhn^{-1}h^{-1} \in N \cap H$ for being both normal, then G is abelian. Thanks for your quick responses

Comment: I've considered the case that b is of order 4. In that case $G \cong D_7 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$. Since the process is very similar as before, I didn't write it all here.

Comment: $G=D_7\times\mathbb Z_2$ doesn't have an element of order $4.$ If $G_1\times G_2$ has an element of order $p^2$, then one of $G_1,G_2$ must have an element of order $p^2.$

Comment: You're right. I thought that (s,1) had order 4. I'll edit the question now.

Comment: There is only one non-trivial semi-direct product $\mathbb Z_7\rtimes \mathbb Z_4,$ with $$(m_1,n_1)\times(m_2,n_2)=\left(m_1+(-1)^{n_1}m_2,n_1+n_2\right)$$

Comment: In particular, for any $m\in\mathbb Z_7,$ we have the $2$-Sylow group: $\{(0,0),(m,1),(0,2),(m,3)\}.$ So there are seven of them.

Comment: Just to be sure, in this final cases, when I have only 2 groups, the problem is reduced to see the different morphisms that exists from one group to the automorphisms of the other one? Could this exercise had been done by saying that I have either $\mathbb{Z}_7 \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_4$ and $\mathbb{Z}_7 \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2 \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2$ with all the different morphisms?

Comment: @DaniSeidler You should put brackets in the semidirect product with $3$ factors. This is not associative.